# How to fix issue while passing ReactJS state data in post request using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am getting an issue with using **Axios**. So, here I want to figure out what I am doing wrong with the **Axios** method.

**React State Data**

This is my data object I am passing as post data.

```
const data = qs.stringify({
            recipe_name: inputs.recipe_name,
            total_serve: inputs.total_serve,
            ingrediants: ingrediants,
            directions: directions
        });
```

**Axios**

```
axios.post(
                'http://example.com/api/add', 
                { data },
                { headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }}
            )
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

**Response:** I have printed the post data on server side. Here is the **problem** the post data is not getting as expectation at server.

```
Array
(
    [{"data":"recipe_name] => Poha
    [total_serve] => 10
    [ingrediants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Ing 1
                    [measure] => 5
                )

        )

    [directions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Direction 1
                    [description] => abc Test Hello test"}
                )

        )

)
```

Starting like this

```
[{"data":"recipe_name] => Poha
```

and ending like this

```
[description] => abc Test Hello test"}
```

I am expecting result like below:

```
Array
(
    [recipe_name] => Poha
    [total_serve] => 10
    [ingrediants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Ing 1
                    [measure] => 5
                )

        )

    [directions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Direction 1
                    [description] => abc test Hello Test
                )

        )

)
```

I want to figure out what I am doing wrong with the Axios method.

Comment: Why are you converting your data object to a string? You don't need to convert data.

Comment: @mafirat its working without converting the data object. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your problem is here

```js
const data = qs.stringify({
   recipe_name: inputs.recipe_name,
   total_serve: inputs.total_serve,
   ingrediants: ingrediants,
   directions: directions
});
```

You do not need to convert your data to string

Try to send raw object

```js
const data = {
   recipe_name: inputs.recipe_name,
   total_serve: inputs.total_serve,
   ingrediants: ingrediants,
   directions: directions
};
```

Comment: I tried that way also it resulting like this:
Array
(
    [{"data":{"recipe_name":"test","total_serve":"test","ingrediants":] => Array
        (
            [{"name":"test","measure":"test"}] => 
        )

)

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Got it bro! got it! 
Actually the problem was having from backend part. Its working without converting to stringify. Thanks